# When new image is added to listview the previous images changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm quite new to listviews. I'm trying to display images in the listview. When I add new item all the previous items change into the new one. So the listview is having same images. I'm done googling and still I can't find the solution. Please help me out. The following is my code.

```
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();

        OpenFileDialog opend1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        opend1.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        opend1.Multiselect = true;

        if (opend1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;

            imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);

            for (int c = 0; c < opend1.FileNames.Length; c++)
            {

                Image i = Image.FromFile(opend1.FileNames[c].ToString());

                Image img = i.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr());

                imageList.Images.Add(img);

            }

            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;

            for (int j = 0; j < imageList.Images.Count; j++)
            {

                ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem();

                lstItem.ImageIndex = j;

                listView1.Items.Add(lstItem);
            }

            listView1.Refresh();

        }
```

Comment: Share your code about what you have tried.

Comment: try setting not only ImageIndex but also StateImageIndex

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ListView` in WinForms, you should put all your images in [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx), and provide only indexes of images in that list to your `ListViewItems`.

```
listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
listView1.SmallImageList = imageList2;
listView1.Items.Add("Foo", 0);
listView1.Items.Add("Bar", 1);
```

It's very simple to create and fill your image lists id designer. Also you can do it manually:

```
imageList1.Images.Add(fooImage); // will have index 0
imageList1.Images.Add(barImage); // will have index 1
```

**UPDATE** Your code looks fine. Is it exact code you have in your application? You only need to simplify it a little:

```
listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);

foreach(var fileName in opend1.FileNames)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName);
    imageList.Images.Add(img.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr()));
}

listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;
for (int index = 0; index < imageList.Images.Count; index++)
     listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { ImageIndex = index });

listView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Excuse me, in `imageList1.Images.Add(fooImage);` I don't have the fooImage. I don't also have the barImage. I'm sorry I have very little knowledge about what I'm doing.

Comment: @user1823223 I have updated sample with your refactored code. And verified it - works like supposed to. Paste it inside `if (opend1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` block.